# How to cast int32 tensor to float32

Tags: python, tensorflow

How can I cast an `int32` tensor to `float32` in tensorflow. I don't understand what `tf.cast` does. It does not seem to do anything.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

tf.enable_eager_execution()

a = tf.constant([[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]])
b = tf.cast(a, dtype=tf.float32)

print(tf.shape(a))
print(tf.shape(b))
```

outputs;

```
tf.Tensor([2 4], shape=(2,), dtype=int32) #a   
tf.Tensor([2 4], shape=(2,), dtype=int32) #b
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just use;

```
print(a)
print(b)
```

you shall get the correct result;

```
tf.Tensor(
[[1 2 3 4]
 [1 2 3 4]], shape=(2, 4), dtype=int32) #a
tf.Tensor(
[[1. 2. 3. 4.]
 [1. 2. 3. 4.]], shape=(2, 4), dtype=float32) #b
```

So the `tf.cast()` works as intended!

---

With [`tf.shape()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/shape) you are getting a result that explains the shape details of input.

> Returns: A Tensor of type out_type.
>
> out_type: (Optional) The specified output type of the operation (int32
>   or int64). Defaults to tf.int32

So the `dtype` of `tf.shape()` result, is the `dtype` of the resulting "*shape detailing tensor*", not of `a`, or `b`